# Datetimepicker shows on bottom of page, not under input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented this datetimepicker for Bootstrap: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It works fine on my PC, but when I open it from a phone browser, the picker doesn't show up under the field. I have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to see it.

Also, the input field is not disabled. Tapping on it brings up the keyboard, and it's possible to enter text manually (I don't want that to be possible). I guess I can disable it in code, but in the examples it looks like it should be disabled by default?

I'll post more code soon, but if anyone already know what may be the problem let me know. Thanks :)

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="startpicker" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Start:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class='input-group date'>
                <input type='text' name="start" class="form-control datepicker" id="startpicker"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sluttpicker" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Slutt:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class='input-group date'>
                <input type='text' name="slutt" class="form-control datepicker" id="sluttpicker" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(
            {
                format: "dd.mm kl.hh:ii",
                autoclose: "true",
                todayBtn: "true",
                minuteStep: 15,
                pickerPosition: "bottom-left"

            }
        );


        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            style: "btn-primary"
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you should try substituting class `col-sm-3` with class `col-xs-3` on the `div` inside `<div class="form-group">`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late but a good option would be to use `data-date-container="#datepicker-container"` and then create a empty div with an id to match the name of the `data-date-container` so in this case its id will be `datepicker-container`

Comment: In this case it would have been even more helpful to provide a fairly complete code sample doing exactly what you are describing.